# Handle websocket send during handshake without message loss

Tags: javascript, websocket, send, handshake

I'd like to achieve the following behavior. Suppose there is a button on the client side which triggers a function that sends a message via a websocket. The first time this function is called, a WebSocket instance is created and then used in the future calls.

Creating a WebSocket instance is non-blocking. The constructor immediately returns a WebSocket object, starting the handshake in the background. A successful connection triggers the onopen callback.

A problem shows up when the second call comes in and the websocket is still performing the handshake (e.g. user makes double click on the button). All the messages need to be queued and sent when the websocket completes the handshake.

The following piece of code uses jQuery and a custom event to gather all messages received during the handshake.

```
var ws = null;

function sendMessage(message) {
    if (!ws) {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com");
        ws.onopen = function() {
            $(document).trigger('handshakeComplete');
        }
    }
    if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.CONNECTING) { // *
            $(document).bind('handshakeComplete', message, function(event) {
                ws.send(event.data);
            });
    } else if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
        // use the persistent connection
        ws.send(message);
    }
}
```

It is possible the condition at the starred line to be evaluated as true and in that moment the websocket passes in the OPEN state, the onopen callback is executed and only after that the current message is added in the queue waiting for the handshakeComplete event. This would result in the loss of messages.

I would like to avoid this and I would appreciate any ideas, comments or suggestions.

Comment: Are you wanting to prevent the sending of the same message (from the same button being clicked twice) only while negotiating the connection, or at all times?

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent sending any messages. Suppose the message would be the timestamp when the button was clicked. With the above code snippet, I can't guarantee that all messages are getting sent.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. When are messages to be discarded? Could you rephrase your paragraph under your code listing a little bit please?

Comment: @fmoga, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worried that handshakecomplete could fire between the test (== CONNECTING) and when the bind() happens, and the message for the handshakecomplete would never be sent.

In theory if all that existed was JS, this would be wrong, since the event wouldn't fire until the current code finished.  However, in reality the event may be generated on another thread in the background, and merely be *run* in the foreground after we reach a stable state.

The answer is to not embed the message in the handshake event handler.  I suggest adding the message to a queue/array, and in the onopen handler process the array.  The onopen event can fire (get queued) while we're executing, but it won't *run* until we hit a stable state (where all the messages are in the queue/array).